# Removing hyper-v and then installing again

Tags: windows-8, virtual-machine, vmware, hyper-v

I have Windows 8 machine with Hyper-V enabled. I have a few VMs with SharePoint installed.

I want to install VMWare but it won't allow me to since Hyper-V is enabled on this machine. So I want to disable Hyper-V from "Turn Windows features on or off" from Control Panel. My question is if I disable Hyper-V and then later enable again, will my existing VMs work fine just like they currently work? Including all settings like network, RAM, HD etc. that I allocated to my VMs?

Or once I have disabled Hyper-V from Control Panel, if I enable it again I will have to remake all VMs again?

Comment: They will be fine.  You can always enable the feature again if something happens.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing actually happens when you remove the Hyper-V role and add it back again. All the virtual machines and their configuration remains as it was earlier. And in case you have a virtual machine on when you are removing the role then it will convert its state to Saved state.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave Hyper-V enabled but use BCDEdit to delete the entry hypervisorlaunchtype, reboot and install VMWare. If you need Hyper-V again, run

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

to get the Hypervisor running again.